# R function rep() in Python (replicates elements of a list/vector)

Tags: python

The R function rep() replicates each element of a vector:

```
> rep(c("A","B"), times=2)
[1] "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

This is like the list multiplication in Python:

```
>>> ["A","B"]*2
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

But with the rep() R function it is also possible to specifiy the number of repeats for each element of the vector:

```
> rep(c("A","B"), times=c(2,3))
[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
```

Is there such a function availbale in Python ? Otherwise how could one define it ? By the way I'm also interested in such a function for duplicating rows of an array.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use `numpy` arrays and the [numpy.repeat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(["A", "B"])
print np.repeat(x, [2, 3], axis=0)

['A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'B']
```

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if there's a built-in available for this, but you can try something like this:

```
>>> lis = ["A", "B"]
>>> times = (2, 3)
>>> sum(([x]*y for x,y in zip(lis, times)),[])
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

Note that `sum()` runs in quadratic time. So, it's not the recommended way.

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip, starmap
>>> from operator import mul
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(mul, izip(lis, times))))
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

**Timing comparions:**

```
>>> lis = ["A", "B"] * 1000
>>> times = (2, 3) * 1000
>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(mul, izip(lis, times))))
1000 loops, best of 3: 713 µs per loop
>>> %timeit sum(([x]*y for x,y in zip(lis, times)),[])
100 loops, best of 3: 15.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think the answer would be better if you straight up removed the `sum(...)` solution that should never be used anyway. And I want to point out that `izip(lis, times)` only works because the input list contains strings. Non-iterables in the input like `lis = [1, 2]` would cause a crash. You should just use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) instead of `mul`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you say "array" and mention R. You may want to use numpy arrays anyways, and then use:

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat(np.array([1,2]), [2,3])
```

EDIT: Since you mention you want to repeat rows as well, I think you should use numpy. `np.repeat` has an axis argument to do this.

Other then that, maybe:

```
from itertools import izip, chain, repeat
list(chain(*(repeat(a,b) for a, b in izip([1,2], [2,3]))))
```

As it doesn't make the assumption you have  a list or string to multiply. Though I admit, passing everything as argument into chain is maybe not perfect, so writing your own iterator may be better.

Answer (score 4):

What do you think about this way?

To repeat a value:

```
>>> repetitions=[]
>>> torep=3
>>> nrep=5
>>> for i in range(nrep):
>>>     i=torep
>>>     repetitions.append(i)
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

To repeat a sequence:

```
>>> repetitions=[]
>>> torep=[1,2,3,4]
>>> nrep= 2
>>> for i in range(nrep):
>>>     repetitions=repetitions+torep
>>> print(repetitions)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = ['A','B']
n = [2, 4]
```

Your example uses strings which are already iterables.
You can produce a result string which is similar to a list.

```
''.join([e * m for e, m in zip(l, n)])
'AABBBB'
```

Update: the list comprehension is not required here:

```
''.join(e * m for e, m in zip(l, n))
'AABBBB'
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Correct...for your solution - But as I write above I suggest to go with a string instead of a list

Comment: but you can skip the list comprehension part and use just : `''.join(e * m for e, m in zip(l, n))`

Answer (score 1):

The following might work for you:

```
>>>[['a','b'],['A','B']]*5


[['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `numpy.repeat` has been mentioned, and that's clearly the equivalent to what you want. But for completenes' sake, there's also `repeat` from the `itertools` standard library. However, this is intended for iterables in general, so it doesn't allow repetions by index (because iterables in general do not have an index defined).

We can use the code given there as a rough equivalent

```
def repeat(object, times=None):
    # repeat(10, 3) --> 10 10 10
    if times is None:
        while True:
            yield object
    else:
        for i in xrange(times):
            yield object
```

to define our own generalised repeat:

```
def repeat_generalised(object, times=None):
    # repeat(10, 3) --> 10 10 10
    if times is None:
        while True:
            yield object
    else:
        for reps, elem in zip(times, object):
            for i in xrange(reps): 
                yield elem
```

The problem of course is that there's a lot of possible edge cases you have to define (What should happen if object and times have a different number of elements?), and that would depend on you individual use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at a clone of `R` `rep`:

```
def rep(x, times = 1, each = 1, length_out = None):
    if not isinstance(times, list):
        times = [times]

    res = ''.join([str(i) * each for i in x])

    if len(times) > 1:   
        res = ''.join(str(i) * m for i, m in zip(x, times))
    else:
        res = ''.join(res * times[0])
    
    if length_out is None:
        return res
    else:
        return res[0:length_out]
```

Reproduces the `R` examples:

```
rep(range(4), times = 2)
rep(range(4), each = 2)
rep(range(4), times = [2,2,2,2])
rep(range(4), each = 2, length_out = 4)
rep(range(4), each = 2, times = 3)
```

with the exception that there is no recycling of shorter vectors/lists (imo this is the *worst* feature of `R`).

Answer (score -2):

my attempt to rep:

```
def rep(x, times=1, each=1, length_out=None):
    try:
        # apply 'each' to x
        r = np.repeat(x, each)
        if not isinstance(times, list):
            times = [times]
        # one dimension in times: do x * 'times'
        if len(times) == 1:
            res = np.tile(r, times)
        # times has to be the same length as x * each
        else:
            if len(times) != len(x) * each:
                raise ValueError("invalid times argument")
            # apply times[i] to each x[i]
            res = []
            for i, t in enumerate(times):
                res.extend(np.repeat(r[i], t))
        res = np.array(res)
        # cut the result to length_out if present
        return res[0:length_out] if length_out else res
    except Exception as msg:
        print(msg)
        return None
```

seems to work if x is a one dimensional array