# Iterate through a list multiple times

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I'd like to iterate through a list multiple times. For example:

```
mylist = [10,2,58]

for i in iterate_multiple_times(mylist, 3):
    print(i)
```

should print:

```
10
2
58
10
2
58
10
2
58
```

The list is very long and I don't want to create nested `for` loops for indentation/style purposes.

Is there a better solution (e.g. from the point of view of auxiliary storage) than the following?

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

for i in chain.from_iterable(repeat(mylist, 3)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: why not nested `for` loops?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R function rep() in Python (replicates elements of a list/vector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235552/r-function-rep-in-python-replicates-elements-of-a-list-vector)

Comment: how about `while i in range(len(mylist)*3)` and `obj = mylist(i%3)`?

Comment: both `repeat` and `chain.from_iterable` are lazy, you aren't creating copies of the whole list

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You have a bunch of errors there... `mylist(i%3)`? `while i in range(...)`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Oops, brain-fart. Meant `mylist[i%3]` and `while i < 3*len(mylist)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, what you have is about as good as it gets. Both `repeat` and `chain.from_iterable` are lazy, you aren't creating copies of the whole list. You may want to extract that into 
a separate function if you use it multiple times

See [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
def ncycles(iterable, n):
    "Returns the sequence elements n times"
    from itertools import chain, repeat
    return chain.from_iterable(repeat(iterable, n)) 
    # the general recipe wraps iterable in tuple()
    # to ensure you can walk it multiple times
    # here we know it is always a list

mylist = [10,2,58]

for i in ncycles(mylist, 3):
    print(i)
```

Comment: @mhawke yes, but didn't think about pulling it out into a function

Comment: Wrapping OP's code in a function is not really an answer though.

Comment: I think it's valid to repost the code from the question as an answer, because it's a very good solution - better than most other solutions that have been posted in other answers. But you should probably explain why it's a good solution. Maybe add a statement like "The code you have already uses the minimum amount of auxiliary storage. One way to improve it would be to wrap it in a function." or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use nested `for` loops in a generator expression:

```
>>> mylist = [10, 2, 58]
>>> for i in (x for _ in range(3) for x in mylist):
...     print(i)
```

Comment: Although this uses nested for loops, which the OP for some unknown reason doesn't like, it's probably the best answer. It's simple and memory efficient.

Comment: I think OP needs to clarify "why not nested `for` loops" before I can upvote this answer. Otherwise, this is a possible solution to a unclear problem.

Comment: @vaultah. True, but this implies (in my opinion) an oxymoron. Indentation and style aren't exclusive. In fact, one can say *indentation is good style*!! Prefix this answer with indentation is good and I'll upvote !

Answer (score -4):

Other than using `itertools` primitives, you can multiply the list:

```
for i in mylist * 3: print(i)
```

Or create your own procedure:

```
def mul(iterable, amount):
   while amount > 0:
      for x in iterable: yield x
      amount -= 1
```

Not much in standard libs/builtins I'm afraid.

Comment: Isn't that pythonic way? And naive generator (as well as any other naive reiterating solution) would break as soon as we substitute any other single-run iterable,

Comment: Your code doesn't work with single-run iterables either... You can't use that as an argument.

Comment: Yes, that is why I called it _naive_ generator.